# python finding substring inside string

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I am trying to find the number of occurrences of a substring in a string inside python. But i need my search to be very specific. Before searching for the substring I remove all the punctuation:

myString.translate(None, string.punctuation)

Now I search for the substring. If I am searching for the substring "hello bob" and inside the string I am searching I have the text "hello bob—something else" or "hello bob'" along with some other text. The two characters '— are not removed when I remove the punctuation because they are non unicode characters and as a result the two strings mentioned above should not be counted as an occurrence of the word "hello bob".

I used the below regex code to try get the correct amount of occurrences, in large files (3000 lines or more) I start to not get the correct number of occurrences of the words

```
counter = 0
searcher = re.compile("hello bob" + r'([^\w-]|$)').search
with open(myFile, 'r') as source:
    for line in source:
        if searcher(line):
            counter += 1
```

Something else I tried

I am trying to use the findAll function because so far it is giving me the correct number of occurrences for a word I enter.

I found this on stackoverflow:

`re.findall(r'\bword\b', read)`

Is there anyway I can use a variable instead of word?

for example I want to use:

```
myPhrase = "hello bob"
re.findall(r'\bmyPhrase\b', read)
```

Which should be the same as:

```
re.findall(r'\bhello bob\b', read)
```

Comment: Give an example input and expected output.

Comment: Look up info on re.findAll()

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this would be very hard to do because the above code works in most instances but fails on texfiles that are big (3000 lines or more)

Comment: @TallChuck could you by any chance give an example please?

Comment: @memoryManagers You need to explain this sentence properly. It is kinda vague now: _"I have the text "hello bob—something else" or "hello bob'" then these two instances should not be counted because removing punctuation will not remove these symbols because they are non unicode characters and the resulting string after removing punctuation would not be "hello bob" also the substring "hello bob" does not need to be case sensitive."_

Comment: sorry I have from java. I think I have a solution to my answer I started looking into the find function I found this on stackoverflow `re.findall(r'\bfoo\b', file)  ` so where it says foo. Instead I want to put a string object there I tried `re.findall(r'\b'+ myObj + '\b'` which doesnt work I also tried `re.findall(r'\b'myObj'\b', read)  ` which doesnt work

Comment: updated post to make it more clear.

Comment: @memoryManagers Include few input strings that should match the regex pattern and few others that should not match.

Comment: The exact word should match and nothing else so if the phrase was "hello bob" then strings that should match would be "hello bob", "hello bob." (because punctuation is removed). Things that shouldnt match is anything thats not removed when punctuation is removed so for example "hello bob¡" or "hel$lo bob" because these two strings contain non unicode chars. Also I want only the exact word so "hello bobby" should not be valid either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform string interpolating using following trick to solve the problem.

```
myphrase = "hello bob"
pattern = r'\b{var}\b'.format(var = myphrase)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.escape(myPhrase)` for variable substitution.

```
read = "hello bob ! how are you?"
myPhrase = "hello bob"
my_regex = r"\b" + re.escape(myPhrase) + r"\b"

counter = 0
if re.search(my_regex, read, re.IGNORECASE):
    counter += 1
else:
    print "not found"
```